# Dataframe assignment not working inside nested for loop

Tags: pandas, dataframe, for-loop, nested

I'm working with a pandas dataframe that has multiple groups:

```
date | group | brand | calculated_value
_______________________________
5    | 1     | x     | 1
6    | 1     | x     | NaN
7    | 1     | x     | NaN
5    | 2     | y     | 1
6    | 2     | y     | NaN
```

Within each date, group, and brand, I have initialized the first instance with a calculated_value. I am iterating through these with nested for loops so that I can update and assign the next sequential date occurrence of calculated_value (within date-group-brand).

The groupby()/apply() paradigm doesn't work for me, because in e.g. the third row above, the function being passed to apply() looks above and finds NaN. It is not a sequential update.

After calculating the value, I am attempting to assign it to the cell in question, using the right syntax to avoid the CopySettings problem:

```
df.loc[ (df.date == 5) & (df.group == 1) & (df.brand == 'x'), "calculated_value" ] = calc_value
```

However, this fails to set the cell, and it remains NaN. Why is that? I've tried searching many terms, but I was not able to find an answer relevant to my case.

I have confirmed that each of the for loops is incrementing properly, and that I'm addressing the correct row in each iteration.

EDIT: I discovered the problem. When I pass the cells to calculate_function as individual arguments, they each pass as a single-value series, and the function returns a single-value series, which cannot be assigned to the NaN cell. No error was thrown on the mismatched assignment, and the for loop didn't terminate.

I fixed this by passing

```
calculate_function(arg1.values[0], arg2.values[0], ...)
```

Extracting the value array and taking its first index seems inelegant and brittle, but the default is a quirky behavior compared what I'm used to in R.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby().idxmin()` to identify the first `date` in each group of `group, band`:

```
s = df.groupby(['group', 'brand']).date.idxmin()

df.loc[s,'calculated_value'] = 1
```

Output:

```
   date  group brand  calculated_value
0     5      1     x               1.0
1     6      1     x               NaN
2     7      1     x               NaN
3     5      2     y               1.0
4     6      2     y               NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

I will do `transform` with `min`

```
s=df.groupby(['group','brand']).date.transform('min')
df['calculated_value']=df.date.eq(s).astype(int)
```